# How to create a matrix using a for loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have three vectors of the same size, `pressure`, `year` and `month`. Basically I would like to create a matrix of pressure values that correspond with the months and years that they were measured using a for loop. It should be `12x100` in order to appear as 12 months going down and 100 years going left to right.

I am just unsure of how to actually create the matrix, besides creating the initial structure. So far I can only find pressure for a single month (below I did January) for all years.

```
A = zeros([12, 100]);
for some_years = 1900:2000
    press = pressure(year == some_years & month == 1)
end
```

And I can only print the pressures for January for all years, but I would like to store all pressures for all months of the years in a matrix. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with variables `pressure`, `year`, and `month`. I would do something like:

### A fairly robust solution using for loops:

```
T = length(pressure); % get number of time periods. I will assume vectors same length
if(length(pressure) ~= T || length(month) ~= T)
   error('length mismatch');
end
min_year = min(year); % this year will correspond to index 1
max_year = max(year); 

A = NaN(max_year - min_year + 1, 12);      % I like to initialize to NaN (not a number)
                                           % this way missing values are NaN
for i=1:T
    year_index = year(i) - min_year + 1;
    month_index = month(i);  % Im assuming months run from 1 to 12
    A(year_index, month_index) = pressure(i);
end
```

### If you're data is SUPER nicely formatted....

If your data has NO missing, duplicate, or out of order year month pairs (i.e. data is formatted like):

```
year      month        pressure
1900          1            ...
1900          2            ...
...          ...           ...
1900         12            ...
1901          1            ...
...          ...           ...
```

Then you could do the ONE liner:

```
A = reshape(pressure, 12, max(year) - min(year) + 1)';
```

Comment: Ok thanks, my data is formatted nicely in the second way you described, however I have one more question if you don't mind. 

Lets say now I have multiple pressure values per month, is there any feasible way to take the means of the values per month and put the means in a new matrix so that it still could be sorted with year going left to right and 12 months going down? I guess what I'm asking is a way to take the mean of every n value in the pressure vector

Comment: @user5983828 Use the first method, initialize everything in A matrix to zero and store a running sum of pressures. Also initialize a Nobs matrix to zero (same size), and store the number of observations for each year/month. The average would then be `AVG = A ./ Nobs;`